# Why can I reference cells in a range that shouldn't exist, and how do I find the last cell?

Tags: excel, excel-2003, vba

This may be a little difficult to explain, so I've written some code to demonstrate. It should just paste and run...

but in a nutshell, if I set a split range ("A1:A5,A7:A11" in the example) and reference the cells by index, there are cells that shouldn't exist in the range. Namely A6 and cells A12 and onwards.

Can anyone explain why this is, and how would I get the last cell in the range? (should be $A$11 in this case)

```
Public Sub RangeTest()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rangeString As String
Dim testRange As Range

Dim count As Integer

Set ws = Sheet1

rangeString = "A1:A5,A7:A11"

Set testRange = ws.Range(rangeString)

Debug.Print "testRange.Range is " & testRange.Address
Debug.Print ""

For Each cell In testRange
count = count + 1
Debug.Print "Cell no:" & count & " address: " & cell.Address

    If count = 6 Then
    Debug.Print ""
    Debug.Print "No cell $A$6$ in testRange"
    Debug.Print ""
    End If

Next cell

Debug.Print ""
Debug.Print "count is equal to range.Count: " & (count = testRange.count)
Debug.Print ""
Debug.Print "rng.Count is " & testRange.count
Debug.Print ""

count = 0

Dim str As String

'why doesn't this give me subscript out of range???
    For i = 1 To testRange.count + 10
        count = count + 1
        str = "Cell no: " & count & " address: " & testRange(i).Address

        If count = 6 Then
        Debug.Print ""
        Debug.Print "Now cell $A$6$ is in the testRange"
        Debug.Print ""
        End If

        If i > testRange.count Then str = str & " ??? (the range only has " & testRange.count & " cells)"
        Debug.Print str
    Next i

Debug.Print
Debug.Print "Cell number 6 = " & testRange(6).Address
Debug.Print ""
Debug.Print "doesn't matter if we use .Cells: " & testRange.Cells(6).Address

Debug.Print testRange.Cells(6).Address & " shouldn't exist in range " & testRange.Address
Debug.Print ""
Debug.Print "using testRange.Count as index we get " & testRange(testRange.count).Address


Debug.Print ""
Debug.Print "And using SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell)"
Debug.Print "the last cell of the range is......"
Debug.Print ""
Debug.Print testRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Address & " ???"


End Sub
```

This gives the below output of my computer which has left me scratching my head... I'm on excel 2003, but I'd be interested to know if later versions of excel give the same results.

```
testRange.Range is $A$1:$A$5,$A$7:$A$11

Cell no:1 address: $A$1
Cell no:2 address: $A$2
Cell no:3 address: $A$3
Cell no:4 address: $A$4
Cell no:5 address: $A$5
Cell no:6 address: $A$7

No cell $A$6$ in testRange

Cell no:7 address: $A$8
Cell no:8 address: $A$9
Cell no:9 address: $A$10
Cell no:10 address: $A$11

count is equal to range.Count: True

rng.Count is 10

Cell no: 1 address: $A$1
Cell no: 2 address: $A$2
Cell no: 3 address: $A$3
Cell no: 4 address: $A$4
Cell no: 5 address: $A$5

Now cell $A$6$ is in the testRange

Cell no: 6 address: $A$6
Cell no: 7 address: $A$7
Cell no: 8 address: $A$8
Cell no: 9 address: $A$9
Cell no: 10 address: $A$10
Cell no: 11 address: $A$11 ??? (the range only has 10 cells)
Cell no: 12 address: $A$12 ??? (the range only has 10 cells)
Cell no: 13 address: $A$13 ??? (the range only has 10 cells)
Cell no: 14 address: $A$14 ??? (the range only has 10 cells)
Cell no: 15 address: $A$15 ??? (the range only has 10 cells)
Cell no: 16 address: $A$16 ??? (the range only has 10 cells)
Cell no: 17 address: $A$17 ??? (the range only has 10 cells)
Cell no: 18 address: $A$18 ??? (the range only has 10 cells)
Cell no: 19 address: $A$19 ??? (the range only has 10 cells)
Cell no: 20 address: $A$20 ??? (the range only has 10 cells)

Cell number 6 = $A$6

doesn't matter if we use .Cells: $A$6
$A$6 shouldn't exist in range $A$1:$A$5,$A$7:$A$11

using testRange.Count as index we get $A$10

And using SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell)
the last cell of the range is......

$C$20 ???
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to use a `For Each...Next` loop to iterate through each cell in the range. When you use the counter the way you are in your code, you aren't actually limiting it to `testrange`. You're really just giving it a place to start when it considers what the counter should do. You're basically telling it to start at `testrange` and then go down this far.

This is why we have different loops available to use. Each one is slightly different and can do slightly different things. The `For Each...Next` loop allows you to limit the loop to just the cells in the range that you specify. When you use a counter, though, it doesn't want to skip over anything(like cell $A$6), and instead of going to the sixth cell in the range(as it seems you intended your code to say), it goes to the sixth cell **from** the start point of the range.

Comment: A range is an array of cells, but the counter isn't looking at your range. It is only looking at the first cell in your range to determine its own starting point. You specifically told it to go 10 beyond the number of cells in the range. The counter won't stay inside of the range because you haven't limited the counter to only cells in the range.

Comment: This is the right answer.  To say how it _should_ behave isn't usfull.  The real question is how _does_ it behave. Answer: how user2970747 describes it.  Some additional info: for a multi area range as the OP defines, `Range(i)` starts at the top left cell of the **First Area** in the range, counting across columns (1 in this case) then down rows.  ie if the range was defined as `"A7:A11,A1:A5"` it would start at `A7`.  Values of `i` < 0 will work too, provided they reference a cell on he sheet (referencing `A0` will, as always, error).

Comment: If you specify only one index `Range(i)` respects the width of the range but not the height.  If you specify both indexes `Range(i, j)` then neither height nor width are respected.  Eg `Range("E10:F12,G4:H6")(0, 0).Address` is `D9`

Answer (score 1):

One way is to traverse the range:

```
Public Function LastCell(rng As Range) As String
    Dim s As String
    For Each r In rng
        s = r.Address(0, 0)
    Next r
    LastCell = s
End Function

Sub MAIN()
    Dim rangeString As String, testRange As Range
    rangeString = "A1:A5,A7:A11"
    Set testRange = Range(rangeString)
    MsgBox LastCell(testRange)
End Sub
```

There may be more efficient solutions.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the answer. I showed that traversing the range worked in the first loop in my example output, so I could do that and it would work. It just doesn't feel right to me. It seems that the `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell)` or getting the cells by index should work..

Comment: **Last Cell** can be ambiguous....What is the last cell in **Range("A1,B1,A2")** ??

Comment: I dislike SpecialCells because of their limitations in functions as compared to subs.

Comment: True.. I don't really use LastCell (or any of the other specialCells) that much, but would expect it to do what it says on the tin for a 1d range array and not give a cell that is obviously outside of the range. It was my second alternative to using `testRange(testRange.count)` which would be my preferred option..

Comment: It just does not work that way.  **MsgBox testRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Address**  will give the address of the last cell in the **used** range, not the last cell in **testRange**.  So if **M100** has stuff in it, thats what MsgBox will report..................try it out.

Comment: Yep. I got `$C$20` in my test script. But I don't think it should be that way based on the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb178148%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

Comment: The documentation for **xlCellTypeLastCell** in VBA Help is EXTREMELY SNEAKY!!!.............read it carefully!!

Comment: It's definitely inconsistent.