# Excel VBA - Union of Ranges and its sub ranges

Tags: vba, excel

Consider the following vba macro in excel

```
Sub foo()
    Dim aRng As Range: Set aRng = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:J1")
    Dim bRng As Range: Set bRng = ActiveSheet.Range("A4:J4")
    Dim cRng As Range: Set cRng = ActiveSheet.Range("A10:J10")

    Dim uRng As Range: Set uRng = Union(aRng, bRng, cRng)
    uRng.Style = "Good"
    uRng.Cells(2, 1).Style = "Bad"
End sub
```

The results are: Rows 1 `"A1:J1", "A4:J4", "A10:J10"` are *good* and cell `"A2"` is *bad*.
I expected cell `"A4"` to be *bad*.  "A2" is not in `uRng`; why would it be returned by `uRng.Cells(2,1)`?

Other oddities: `uRng.Rows.Count = 1` and `uRng.Columns.Count = 10`. Am I wrong to expect `uRng` to be 3x10 range?  Or is that undefined because the positions of `aRng`, `bRng`, and `cRng` to each other is not specified?

Comment: I asked a question about ranges yesterday.. They don't behave how you would expect :( [My Range Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035121/why-can-i-reference-cells-in-a-range-that-shouldnt-exist-and-how-do-i-find-the)

Comment: it's easy to check. Just fill your range (leave any other cells blank) and do a `Application.Worksheetfunction.CountaA(uRng)`. Thus you can see the no. of filled cells vs. expected.

Comment: I see you have already accepted an answer :) But I will still go ahead and post my answer since I typed a lot... lol

Comment: It will be appreciated

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They are actually treated as three separate ranges, accessible from `uRng` via the `Range.Areas` property:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.areas(v=office.11).ASPX

Using your example, here's how to get `A4` included, as the first cell in the second range:

```
Sub foo()
    Dim aRng As Range: Set aRng = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:J1")
    Dim bRng As Range: Set bRng = ActiveSheet.Range("A4:J4")
    Dim cRng As Range: Set cRng = ActiveSheet.Range("A10:J10")

    Dim uRng As Range: Set uRng = Union(aRng, bRng, cRng)
    uRng.Style = "Good"
    uRng.Areas(2).Cells(1, 1).Style = "Bad"
End Sub
```

also, the code below will give you same result:

```
Sub foo2()
    Dim uRng As Range: Set uRng = [A1:J1,A4:J4,A10:J10]
    uRng.Style = "Good"
    uRng.Areas(2).Cells(1, 1).Style = "Bad"
End Sub
```

Comment: Interesting... `uRng.Areas(2).Cells(2,1).Select` selects "A5". Thanks

Answer (score 4):

**A** `uRng.Cells(2, 1)` works only for contiguous ranges and not non-contiguous range. To select a cell in a particular area, you have to address that area and then use `.Cells(r,w)`

For example

```
uRng.Areas(n).Cells(r, c)
```

Where `n` is the area which you want to write to and `r`, `c` are the row/column.

**B.** Rows.Count works with 1 Area. So to find the rows count in a non-contiguous range, you will have to loop though it.

See this example

```
Option Explicit

Sub foo()
    Dim aRng As Range: Set aRng = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:J1")
    Dim bRng As Range: Set bRng = ActiveSheet.Range("A4:J4")
    Dim cRng As Range: Set cRng = ActiveSheet.Range("A10:J10")
    Dim rngArea As Range
    Dim rwCount As Long

    Dim uRng As Range: Set uRng = Union(aRng, bRng, cRng)

    If uRng.Areas.Count > 1 Then
        Debug.Print "It's a non-contiguous range"
        For Each rngArea In uRng.Areas
            rwCount = rwCount + rngArea.Rows.Count
        Next
        Debug.Print "The range has " & rwCount & " rows"
    Else
        Debug.Print "It's a contiguous range"
        Debug.Print "The range has " & uRng.Rows.Count & " rows"
    End If
End Sub
```

**C.** There is an oddity in `columns.count` as well but since all the range had same number of columns, you didn't relaize this. Try this

```
Option Explicit

Sub foo()
    Dim aRng As Range: Set aRng = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:J1")
    Dim bRng As Range: Set bRng = ActiveSheet.Range("A4:K4") '<~~ I changed this.
    Dim cRng As Range: Set cRng = ActiveSheet.Range("A10:J10")

    Dim uRng As Range: Set uRng = Union(aRng, bRng, cRng)

    '~~> This will still give you 10 instead of `11`
    Debug.Print uRng.Columns.Count
End Sub
```

So the same logic applies to find the number of columns as well.

**IMP**: Now It depends on how you want to count the number of rows/columns. What if the rows/columns of the areas overlap? In such a case do you want to total count of the rows/columns or the actual Excel rows/columns in this non contiguous range?

Comment: Next time I will wait a few hours before selecting an answer

Comment: I noticed that if I used `"A2:J2"` instead of `"A4:K4"` then there would be two areas of 2x10 and 1x10.  So Areas is dependent on which ranges are separate not which ranges were unioned.

Comment: True because `aRng` and `bRng` become one contiguous range `A1:J2` :)