# Looping through sales data and move sales over a certain amount to a new worksheet

Tags: windows, vba, spreadsheet

I've tried looking all over this website but can't find anything too similar. What I am looking to do is ask the user for input on a target value they would like to search for. Then, I want the program to loop through the sales data and for each value it finds greater than the user input, copys this data to a new worksheet.

```
Sub Task1()
Dim LastRow As Integer, i As Integer, erow As Integer
Dim wsnew As Worksheet
Dim userInput As Long
Dim compare As Integer


LastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
userInput = InputBox("Enter a value to search for:")

Set wsnew = Worksheets.Add(after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count))
wsnew.name = "Report"
Worksheets("Report").Range("A1").Value = "Dollar sales over $" & userInput
Worksheets("Report").Range("A1").Font.Bold = True

For i = 2 To LastRow
    compare = Cells(i, 3).Value
    If compare > userInput Then
        Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 3)).Select
        Selection.Copy
        Worksheets("Report").Select
        erow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
        ActiveSheet.Cells(erow, 1).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: And what is your code doing differently from your objective?

Comment: If the sales data is all in one sheet I would suggest using [Union](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20055984/excel-vba-union-of-ranges-and-its-sub-ranges) to collect the ranges where a greater value is found and then copy that across in one go. It will be more efficient.

Comment: AFAIK, you could use `Advanced Filter` to do the task. See if [this](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2016/09/07/excel-advanced-filter/) helps.

Answer (score 0):

Untested, written on mobile.

You could also use AutoFilter instead, or advanced filter if you're happy to allocate a sheet/range to store the criteria.

```
Option explicit

Sub Task1()
Dim LastRow As long
Dim SourceSheet As Worksheet
Dim DestinationSheet
Dim userInput As Long

Set SourceSheet = ActiveSheet

LastRow = SourceSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
' You could specify type argument below to limit to numeric types and for basic validation.'
userInput = InputBox("Enter a value to search for:")

Set DestinationSheet = Worksheets.Add(after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count))

With DestinationSheet
.name = "Report"
With .Range("A1")
.Value2 = "Dollar sales over $" & userInput
.Font.Bold = True
End with

' Minimise interactions with worksheet. '
Dim RawValues() as variant
RawValues = SourceSheet.range("A2:C" & lastrow).value2

Dim FilteredValues() as variant
Redim FilteredValues(lbound(RawValues,1) to ubound(RawValues,1), lbound(RawValues,2) to ubound(RawValues,2))

' 3 = column C. Change line below if it changes. '
Const COMPARISON_COL_NUM as long = 3

Dim WriteIndex as long
Dim RowIndex as long
Dim ColumnIndex as long
Dim ColumnUbound as long
ColumnUbound= ubound(FilteredValues,2) ' instead of re-determining for each row '

For RowIndex = lbound(RawValues,1) to ubound(RawValues,1)

If RawValues(RowIndex COMPARISON_COL_NUM) > userinput then

WriteIndex = WriteIndex + 1
For ColumnIndex = 1 to ColumnUbound
FilteredValues(WriteIndex,ColumnIndex) = RawValues(RowIndex, ColumnIndex)
Next ColumnIndex

End if

Next RowIndex

' You could Redim Preserve FilteredValues to 1 to WriteIndex, 1 to ColumnUbound, so that you get rid of empty rows, but you would have to transpose the array first. '

'Write only values back to sheet. '
With range("A2").resize(ubound(FilteredValues,1),ubound(FilteredValues,2))
.value2 = FilteredValues

' Assumes cell formatting does not differ from row to row on the source sheet.
SourceSheet.range("A2:C2").copy
.pastespecial xlpasteformats
Application.cutcopymode = false

End with

End with


End Sub
```